# RuntimeError: ; eglGetDisplay() returned error 0x3000ontext_egl.cc:157)

Tags: python, mediapipe

I am trying to run python code using `mediapipe` library. I am using `mp.solutions.pose`. I am getting the error in the line

```
pose = mpPose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=1)
```

I do not understand what it means. Kindly suggest solution.

Comment: read this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962618/opengl-egl-eglgetdisplay-keeps-return-egl-error-0x3008egl-bad-display

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using MediaPipe on an Nvidia Jetson Nano through ssh. The solution was to specify which display to use and running MediaPipe with DRI_PRIME=1. The full command would be:

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && DRI_PRIME=1 <command>
```

Read https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1483#issuecomment-765811256 for details on how to specify the display.